# backup and restore from 32 to 64 bit os

Tags: upgrade, system

If I backup my Data files on my existing 32bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system then do a fresh install of 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 Lts. Will Restore work correctly to reinstall the data files from the 32bit system on the 64 bit system. Using Ubuntu built in backup and restore programme.

Comment: What 32 bit files are you asking about ?

Comment: I refer to the files I have created in the various apps e.g. libre office. not the apps themselves.

Answer (score 3):

In general you won't want to restore 32-bit binary files to your new 64-bit Ubuntu. Only data, that is documents, music, photos and so on. And source code and scripts, if you have any you have developed your self.

Applications should be reinstalled in 64-bit versions, if they are not included directly in Ubuntu. And any source-files compiled on the new system.

In general you will only want to restore your home-directory, and special "project" directories, if you have any.

Comment: Thats correct I mean the documents I have created and saved in files.  I assume from your comment that I can restore my 32bit home directory to the new 64 bit home directory am I correct.